# MySql add relationships without creating dupes

Tags: mysql, database, duplicates

I created a table (t_subject) like this

```
| id | description | enabled |
|----|-------------|---------|
| 1  | a           | 1       |
| 2  | b           | 1       |
| 3  | c           | 1       |
```

And another table (t_place) like this

```
| id | description | enabled |
|----|-------------|---------|
| 1  | d           | 1       |
| 2  | e           | 1       |
| 3  | f           | 1       |
```

Right now data from `t_subject` is used for each of `t_place` records, to show HTML dropdowns, with all the results from `t_subject`.

So I simply do

`SELECT * FROM t_subject WHERE enabled = 1`

Now just for one of `t_place` records, one record from `t_subject` should be hidden.
I don't want to simply delete it with javascript, since I want to be able to customize all of the dropdowns if anything changes.

So the first thing I though was to add a `place_id` column to `t_subject`.
But this means I have to duplicate all of `t_subject` records, I would have 3 of each, except one that would have 2.

Is there any way to avoid this??

I thought adding an `id_exclusion` column to `t_subject` so I could duplicate records only whenever a record is excluded from another id from `t_place`.

How bad would that be?? This way I would have no duplicates, so far.

Hope all of this makes sense.

Comment: What's the relation between these two tables? I assume this is a database for locations where subjects can be taken? In that case, I assume this is a many-to-many relationship?

Comment: There's no relation at this time. I didn't care to have one, since for each location I needed all of the subjects...but now I have to exclude one subject from one location...
I added a `id_location_exclusion` column and added a foreign key constraint to `t_place` id column

Comment: The bad thing here is that I'll have to `distinct` results to avoid duplicates in the future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you only need to exclude one course, I would still recommend setting up a full 'place-course' association. You essentially have a many-to-many relationship, despite not explicitly linking your tables.

I would recommend an additional 'bridging' or '[associative entity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity)' table to represent which courses are offered at which places. This new table would have two columns - one foreign key for the ID of `t_subject`, and one for the ID of `t_place`.

For example (`t_place_course`):

```
| place_id | course_id |
|----------|-----------|
| 1        | 1         |
| 1        | 2         |
| 1        | 3         |
| 2        | 1         |
| 2        | 2         |
| 2        | 3         |
| 3        | 1         |
| 3        | 3         |
```

As you can see in my example above, place `3` doesn't offer course `2`.

From here, you can simply query all of the courses available for a place by querying the `place_id`:

```
SELECT * from t_place_course WHERE place_id = 3
```

The above will return both courses `1` and `3`.

You can optionally use a `JOIN` to get the other information about the course or place, such as the description:

```
    SELECT `t_course`.`description`
      FROM `t_course`
INNER JOIN `t_place_course`
        ON `t_course`.`id` = `t_place_course`.`course_id`
INNER JOIN `t_place`
        ON `t_place`.`id` = `place_id`
```

Comment: Another alternative would be to create an "exclusion" table `t_place_course_exclude`, and we could store the single row `(3,2)`.  Then we could use a cross join between t_place and t_course, with an anti-join to the exclusion table.  e.g. `... FROM t_course c CROSS JOIN t_place p LEFT JOIN t_course_place_exclude x ON x.place_id = p.id AND x.course_id = c.id WHERE x.place_id IS NULL ...`

Comment: yeah that also could do the job...but I think Obsidian's way is cleaner!

Comment: just deployed in production! Thanks again works like charm!! :D